# Finding rightmost greater element in array with positive integers Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a code logic to find the farthest right greater element than a given element.
For example, if input array is `[3,7,9,4,1]` then output should be `[4, 9, 9, 4, 1]`. Notice that since `9` is the greatest element, it will remain unchanged, and similarly with the element on the right boundary.

Here is my working code for it,

```
def rightmost_greater(arr):
     n=len(arr)
     left=0
     right=n-1
     L=[]
     while left<=right:
         if arr[left]>arr[right]:
              right-=1
         elif arr[left]==arr[right]:
              L.append(arr[left])
              left+=1   # move to next element
              right=n-1  # reset the right pointer
         else:
             L.append(arr[right])
             left+=1   # move to next element
             right=n-1  # reset the right pointer
        
    return L
```

As you can see, this code seems quite wordy, I'm resetting the right pointer several times; is it possible to use an efficient way to write the code(preferably recursive logic). Advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Humble request to the admin/moderators, kindly let me know why the question has been downvoted. I tried to give all relevant details to the best of my knowledge.  Your clarification will help me in posting future questions. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution with almost the same logic but a recursive one and a little efficient. see if this helps.

```
arr=[3,7,9,4,1]
n=len(arr)
L=[]

def rightmost_greater(arr,left,right):
     if left<=right:
         if arr[left]>arr[right]:
              rightmost_greater(arr,left,right-1)
         else:
             L.append(arr[right])
             rightmost_greater(arr,left+1,n-1)

rightmost_greater(arr,0,n-1)
print(L)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.Highly appreciate it. I am learning recursion rt now, hence trying to rewrite most of my iterative codes, if possible in recursive manner.